# How to connect linked service in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have created a dedicated pool in azure synapse service but I'm unable to select the server in linked services in Azure data factory.

public endpoint have access and also In synpase networking i have allowed access for azure services but nothing is working

Comment: Hi Nethala
Can you check if you are providing the correct server name and authentication details in the linked service configuration in Azure Data Factory.
Also confirm that the server's firewall settings are configured to allow connections from the IP address of the machine running Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a linked service for Azure synapse dedicated pool.

You can follow the below steps:

**Step 1:**  Create the Linked service for Azure SQL database

[image]

**Step 2:** Go to Synapse overview and copy the dedicated sql pool server name.

[image]

**Step 3:** While creating the linked service choose the account selection method choose as **ENTER MANUALLY**

[image]

Provide the dedicated sql server name that you have obtained from synapse overview.

**Step 4:** Provide the SQL Authenication credentails and test connection.

[image]

**Reference:**  [Load data into dedicated SQL pool using the copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-copy-activity-load-sql-pool)